# Code structure for iOS with Swift, what goes where, all code?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

So I'm new with iOS but seasoned with Android and I'm starting to get the gist of most stuff but I have a hard time understanding what goes where, why it is like this...

When you use storyboards only it's easy enough to implement MVC pattern (or any other view seperation pattern), but when you make everything in code I feel it gets little messy.

Lets say I have a ViewController with a parent View containing children Views, which again might contain children Views. Now where should I create the children? In the ViewController (most convenient) or in the parent View (nearest)?

If I use the ViewController I have reference and I'll have an easy time making outlets etc. but should the ViewController then also do stuff like setTitle, setImage, background etc. etc.? This will definitely be the easiest solution. The disadvantage is that Views are simply just objects making which will result in the ViewController becoming bloated.

If I use the View I'll have a hard time returning outlets to the ViewController and the ViewController will end up doing nearly nothing.

Apple isn't much help either, the officiel FoodTracker tutorial shows both ViewController and Views using outlets etc. etc.

Basic structure I have right now:

```
updateLayoutStates()
setupLayoutPositions()
updateLayoutPositions()

...

/// Setups the initial constraints for all views
func setupLayoutPositions() {

    // add views by order of appearances
    addSubview(languageBtn)
    addSubview(playBtn)
    addSubview(menuBtn)
    //addSubview(barScrollOverlayView)
    addSubview(barScrollView)
    addSubview(collapseBtn)

    // add bar scroll inner subviws by order of appearance
    barScrollView.addSubview(barScrollContentView)

    barScrollContentView.addSubview(speedContainerView)
    barScrollContentView.addSubview(speedProgress)
    barScrollContentView.addSubview(readingStratBtn)
    // More code that adds constraints etc. etc.

...

/**
 Updates all views based on the current status of the bar
 */
func updateLayoutStates() {
    print("Bar updateLayoutStates")

    // setup base layout
    // setup permanent items, listed by appearance
    languageBtn.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.dark_blue, alpha: 1)
    languageBtn.setTitle("lang_da".localized, forState: .Normal)
    languageBtn.postSetup()
    languageBtn.setTitleColor(UIColorFromHex(Constants.Colors.white, alpha: 1), forState: .Normal)

    playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Play"), forState: .Normal)
    playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "PlayActive"), forState: .Highlighted)
    playBtn.setTitle("label_play_key".localized, forState: .Normal)
    playBtn.postSetup()

   ...

/// updates the positions of all layouts based on the current status of the bar
func updateLayoutPositions() {
    if currentBarState == BarState.EnabledStandardExpanded {
        self.removeConstraint(collapseLeftConstraint)
        self.addConstraint(collapseRightConstraint)
    } else if currentBarState == BarState.EnabledStandardCollapsed {
        self.removeConstraint(collapseRightConstraint)
        self.addConstraint(collapseLeftConstraint)
    }
}
```

All explanation with examples is greatly appreciated and I'll be happy to explain further if I haven't been clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At one hand you are talking about good architecture. On the other hand you want some help with your specific view structure.

**1)** For the first part you have many resources out there. DJohnsen already mentioned MVVM and VIPER which I think is a good search string for Google.
I think it is always good to get comfortable with architecture topics. And every architecture has trade offs.
A good starting point is Uncle Bobs "Clean Code".

- Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship (Robert C. Martin) [https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

From there many ideas evolved.

**2)** Regarding your view problem:

If you have a nested view hierarchy it might be a good idea to think of **view controller containment**. As soon as you see, that your view is composed out of many other views and it gets more complex you might want to split the components.
You always have to think about the concrete problem you are trying to solve:

- Do you only want to display one label and a button? Add them directly to the view controller and connect the outlets or setup target/action.
- Do you have a complex view with headers, custom subviews, maybe also a tableView etc? Use **child view controllers**

But to break it down:

View controllers and views are very close to each other.
In iOS I started to handle views and view controllers in the following way:

- Views controllers should be dumb. Their only purpose is to manage child controllers or to set properties of a few views. View controllers also manage high level screen handling (device rotation, status bar handling etc) and talk with the presentation layer.
- Views are more dumb and should only setup the subviews, layout (set Layout constraints) and provide some methods for customization (which can be used by the view controller).

It all sounds a bit hard: But I think it is a good guideline for beginners. After some time you will get comfortable.

The questions you ask are good ones but you will answer them by yourself after some time. I think the most important thing is that you should put only view specific code into view controllers and views. Not more.

All the rest quickly escalates to religious wars :)

Cheers
Orlando

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to come to a better understanding of everything. Also I've realised there is no one answer for this :). From Android perspective I guess the ViewController is similar to a Fragment. In Android it's also possible to mess everything up as you please as soon as you do UI in code and not in xml.

Comment: Yes. One can say that a ViewController is like an Activity or Fragment in Android. And I hope you understood what was meant with "view controller containment". If not: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: Yes this was already the approach I had decided to go. I had started out with a simple view that had gotten more and more complex at which point I realised it was a child viewcontroller :) but as you stated, we can still code it like that, it's just not a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways/patterns to address this and avoid view controller bloat.  After looking at MVC, VIPER, MVVM and many others, I like much of the implementation of [Clean Swift](http://clean-swift.com/).  It supports single use functions, dependency injection, and keeps the view controller very clean.

While at first it seemed to be overkill (and for very small projects it likely is) - I recently refactored an OS X project that was growing unwieldy.  It's amazing how simple it is now to implement new features, isolate bugs and reuse code.  Might be worth checking out?

**The Bad News** - If you ask a thousand developers their opinion on this, you'll get at least a thousand opinions.

**The Good News** - The platform is flexible enough for all of them!

Apple provides MVC guidelines here, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html, and I'll give you my view on it:

With a very basic example of an app to pick and schedule conference rooms:

**Model**
As you are aware, Models represent data structures.  I keep 1 file per struct/class and I keep the code to only representing the data (not business logic).  My Conference Room Model might look something like:

```
struct ConferenceRoom {
    let maxOccupancy: Int
    let roomNumber: Int
    let hasProjector: Bool
    var reservations: 
}
```

**Controller**
I try to keep business logic in controllers (not to be confused with ViewControllers).  For example:

```
class ConferenceRoomController {
  var conferenceRooms = [ConferenceRoom]()

  init() {
    ...
  }

  func retrieveConferenceRoomsFromDatastore() -> [ConferenceRoom] {
    ...
  }

  func reserveConferenceRoom(roomNumber: Int, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Bool {
    ...

  }

  func findRoomsForDateWithCapacity(capacity: Int, date: NSDate) -> [ConferenceRoom] {
    ...
  }
}
```

**View**
This is often a View/ViewController.  In IOS, a ViewcController is both the view, and the controller for managing the view, which is a point of confusion for many people, and because it can do basically anything, too much business logic or other code ends up here (bloat).  I try to only put functions related to displaying data here (not what to display - that's the Controller).  If I am adding subviews to the view progmatically, I do that here as well.

```
class ConferenceRoomScheduler: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var numberOfParticipants: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var reservationDate: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet var submitButton: UIButton!

  let conferenceRoomController = ConferenceRoomController()

  @IBAction func submitButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let participants = Int(numberOfParticipants.text!)
    if let participants = participants {
      conferenceRoomController.findRoomsForDateWithCapacity(participants, date: NSDate())
    } else {
      print("Not a number")
    }
  }
}
```

These classes are not complete, but hopefully provide some example of what to put where.  I find these types of decisions evolve as you get more comfortable developing for the platform.  I agree - some of the patters, such as Clean-Swift seem like you would spend a lot of time 'plumbing', and you might if you aren't familiar with the specific implementation.  For example, when I started IOS development I could spend hours putting together a simple tableView and it seemed so complicated.  Now, after having done it too many times to count, a fully functioning tableView with functionality beyond beyond the basics takes just a few minutes to setup.  Application architecture works the same for me.  Clean-Swift (and others) don't seem too heavy anymore (and the benefits out weigh the initial perceived complexity).

Comment: Yes it all sounds great, but by seperation everything into use cases I'll spend a lot of time doing plumping. This seems like even more work that MVVM pattern. But my problem is actually more simple than this. My problem is simply when do I put functional code in views and when do I put it in ViewController, is there any guidelines or isn't there? The above code I've supplied started out in a view and has since been moved to ViewController. Both ways work but what is preferred?

Comment: @DJohnson: I have one problem with the concept on clean-swift.com. The author sets up circular dependencies with VC -> I -> P -> VC. I think it is not good to have a direct dependency from the view controller to the interactor. This means the view controller knows the business logic interface. From my point of view a VC should only communicate that the user triggered any event and it gets any results pushed from the presentation layer... but I don't want to start a flame war here ;)